# Android-Read Data From Firebase Real Time Database and Displaying on RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have successfully been able to save data in RTD of Firebase using 
`databaseIngredients.child(StringId).setValue(ingredients);`
Where the "ingredients" is a String taken from EditText and StringId is a unique ID by the "push" method. I have referred to many tutorials but I am not able to read it, I want to update my RecyclerView every time my database is updated with new data. I just want to display all data in my Database using recyclerView. The ValueEventListener method is not understood by me. Please be patient as I understand the reply, new to Firebase.

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading data is very simple, all you need to do is `set a listener` that listens for `change in value` in the `database reference` you provided.

There are two listeners for that purpose,

- One Time Listener(`addListenerForSingleValueEvent`), which only reads data once you make request. For this,

DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Database").child(StringId).setValue(ingredients);

```
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapShot.exists()){
            //update recyclerview or do anything with your data
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

- Continuous Data Listener(`addValueEventListener`), which is used to get data every time it changes in server

  DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Database").child(StringId).setValue(ingredients);

  ```
      reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if(dataSnapShot.exists()){
                  //update recyclerview or do anything with your data
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help, but how will I display my data In the RecyclerView?

Comment: That is very simple too. There are many ways you can do it. This simple example will help you. :)
https://www.android-examples.com/show-firebase-database-data-into-recyclerview/

Answer (score 0):

You can use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter . You'll need a model class and a ViewHolder class.
If you're using new version of `firebase-ui` then you have to use FirebaseRecyclerOptions along with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

[Here's the official documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)